# how to make a python websocket server return things?

Tags: python, websocket

is it possible to create a websocketSERVER like this
that i can have inside a method, or class?

```py
#THIS IS PSEUDOCODE, any changes inside this method dont matter
async def step(action):
    await data = websocket.recv()
    websocket.send(action)
    return data
```

my client sends an initial request, then always responds to the servers commands.

Comment: usually you just subscribe to ws.onmessage or something ... socket.recv() looks more like traditional normal socket communication

Comment: the problem is that the client comes from a browser via js

Comment: no one knows what your asking as what you show is not how websockets normally work.... but yes you can certainly handle client requests in an async method